# Execution Timed Out How can I optimize this kata to run faster?

Tags: c#

i am a beginner in c# and i found this kata on codewars "Sum of Intervals" I've coded a solution but it says Execution Timed Out when i attempt to solve it even though the sample tests pass perfectly; i am hoping for someone to help me optimize it.
Here is my Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Interval = System.ValueTuple<int, int>;

public class Intervals
{
   public static int SumIntervals((int, int)[] intervals)
   {
        if (intervals.Length == 0) return 0;
        List<int>[] arr = new List<int>[intervals.Length];
        List<int> lst = new List<int>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach((int, int) item in intervals)
        {
            arr[i] = new List<int>();
            for (int j = item.Item1; j <= item.Item2; j++)
            {
                arr[i].Add(j);
            }
            i++;
        }
        int indx = 0;
        lst = arr[0].Union(arr[1]).ToList();
        bool bl = true;
        for (indx = 0; indx < arr.Length; )
        {
            bl = true;
            for (int k = 0; k < arr.Length; k++)
            {
                if (k == indx)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (arr[indx].Intersect(arr[k]).Count() == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    bl = false;
                    lst = arr[indx].Union(arr[k]).ToList();
                    lst.Sort();
                    arr[indx] = lst.Distinct().ToList();
                    arr[k].Clear();
                }
            }
            if (bl == true) indx++;

        }
        int count = 0;
        foreach (List<int> lstt in arr)
        {

            if (lstt.Count() > 0)
            {
                count += lstt[lstt.Count() - 1] - lstt[0];
            }

        }
        return count;
   }
   }
```

------------------------------------EDIT----------------------------------------

After some thinking i coded this solution, it works just fine hope you notify me if it should be better.
Here is my code:

```
 if (intervals.Length == 0) return 0;
        bool bl;
        for (int i = 0; i < intervals.Length; )
        {
            bl = true;
            if (intervals[i].Item1 == 0 && intervals[i].Item2 == 0)
            {
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < intervals.Length; j++)
            {
                if ((intervals[j].Item1 == 0 && intervals[j].Item2 == 0) || 
                     j == i) continue;
                else if (intervals[j].Item1 <= intervals[i].Item2 && 
                        intervals[j].Item2 > intervals[i].Item2 && 
                        intervals[j].Item1 > intervals[i].Item1)
                {
                    intervals[i] = (intervals[i].Item1, intervals[j].Item2);
                    bl = false;
                    intervals[j] = (0, 0);
                }
                else if (intervals[i].Item1 <= intervals[j].Item2 && 
                         intervals[i].Item1 > intervals[j].Item1 && 
                         intervals[i].Item2 > intervals[j].Item2)
                {
                    intervals[i] = (intervals[j].Item1, intervals[i].Item2);
                    bl = false;
                    intervals[j] = (0, 0);
                }
                else if (intervals[i].Item1 <= intervals[j].Item1 && 
                         intervals[i].Item2 >= intervals[j].Item2)
                {
                    intervals[j] = (0, 0);
                }
                else if (intervals[j].Item1 <= intervals[i].Item1 && 
                         intervals[j].Item2 >= intervals[i].Item2)
                {
                    intervals[i] = (intervals[j].Item1, intervals[j].Item2);
                    bl = false;
                    intervals[j] = (0, 0);
                }
                else continue;
            }
            if (bl == true)
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        int count = 0;
        foreach ((int, int) item in intervals)
        {
            count += item.Item2 - item.Item1;
        }
        return count;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/52b7ed099cdc285c300001cd) exercise, or something close to it, in which case, you've got way too much code for the task given. The biggest problem I see is with the algorithm itself. I'm giving a suggestion in next paragraph, but I urge you to think about simplifying the algorithm  for yourself before reading the suggestion. Hint - the task can be done with just 3 variables - two ints and an int array.

My suggestion would be: sort array of intervals by interval start, then iterate it once accumulating the value of 'end of current interval' - max('start of current interval', 'end of previous interval').

Also, please make sure to read the book or watch the video series Clean Code by Robert C. Martin and learn to split big functions into smaller functions with different levels of details.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks ok, though you're doing a bunch of steps you don't have to do. I'm probably missing the same thing you are, but your solution is overly verbose. You should be able to just do

```
intervals.Select(x=> Math.Abs(x.Item1 - x.Item2)).Sum()
```

One thing, which is probably meaningless for this scenario, however, instead of `Collection.Length > 0` use `Collection.Any()` - With  the former, it would have to count all the items to see it's greater than 0, with the latter, it sees there's at least 1, and says we're good to go....

Further, you keep accumulating intermediary results in arrays; there's no need if I 've understood the problem correctly, it's all just aggregating.

You could optimize even further and do

```
intervals.Aggregate((total,x) => total + Math.Abs(x.Item1 - x.Item2))
```